# How to fully upgrade to KUbuntu 12.10 from Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I have customized Ubnutu but I want to upgrade to Kubuntu and save only some programs and configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up the files you want, then download Kubuntu onto a disk/on your computer. Follow the easy on-screen steps to get and make the most out of it!

Enjoy!

**Edit**: Wait, does it say 'Upgrade'?

Comment: Where does the OP mention Xubuntu?..

Comment: Ahh.. mean Kubuntu. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You would upgrade to 12.10 and then install `kubuntu-desktop`

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuantalUpgrades

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

If you are wanting to switch to KDE, it may be easier to simply back up your data and perform a fresh install.

Comment: What if I have a lot of apps I installed/configured and I don't wanna start selectively backing up stuff - if I install `kubuntu-desktop`, would the migration be more difficult? What would the process be in order to start using KDE instead of GNOME by default afterwards?

Comment: In general, the more apps you have installed, the more potential for problems when you upgrade. Why would you want to install all of kubuntu-desktop just to then upgrade all those apps ? You can have as many desktops installed as you wish, but the menus get cluttered as you tend to have duplicat apps. Other then that , you select your desktop at login.